# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createStaticVNode) is not a function

Tags: webpack, laravel-8, vuejs3

Having error after installing laravel ui and vue auth scaffloading using the commands bellow:

```
composer require laravel/ui "^1.0" --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

in laravel 8 with vue3 trying to fix the issue in many ways like deleting the node_modules and the running `npm install` but not working.
any idea?

***Error:***

```
app.js:37253 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createStaticVNode) is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue?vue&type=template&id=299e239e&bindings={} (app.js:37253)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:49284)
    at Module../resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue?vue&type=template&id=299e239e&bindings={} (app.js:37229)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:49284)
    at Module../resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue (app.js:37179)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:49284)
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:1966)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:49284)
    at checkDeferredModulesImpl (app.js:49385)
    at Function.__webpack_require__.x (app.js:49403)
./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue?vue&type=template&id=299e239e&bindings={}   @   app.js:37253
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:49284
./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue?vue&type=template&id=299e239e&bindings={}    @   app.js:37229
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:49284
./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue  @   app.js:37179
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:49284
./resources/js/app.js   @   app.js:1966
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:49284
checkDeferredModulesImpl    @   app.js:49385
__webpack_require__.x   @   app.js:49403
(anonymous) @   app.js:49444
(anonymous)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in the following way:
I went back to clean installed laravel and followed this [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-set-up-and-use-vue-in-your-laravel-8-app-2dd0f174e1f8) from second step.

then I run "php artisan ui vue --auth" and then "npm install && npm run dev"

and it began to work correctly